# Difference between border ridge and groove styles

Tags: html, css

I want to know the **difference** **between** border styles- **ridge and groove**. When i used them, i was not able to spot the difference between the two. I cannot upload the image since i have not reached level 10 to make it more clear. Here's the code:

```
border-style: groove ridge dashed groove;
```

Comment: See [**MDN - Border Style**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's border shadow position:

[Ridge: from top left](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_border-style&preval=ridge)
[Groove: from bottom right](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_border-style&preval=groove)

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  background-color: white;
}
.wrap {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}
#ridge {
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: ridge;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
#groove {
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: groove;
  margin-left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div id="ridge">ridge</div>
  <div id="groove">groove</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The difference is defined in somewhat vague terms in the [CSS 2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#value-def-border-style):

**groove**
     The border looks as though it were carved into the canvas.

**ridge**
     The opposite of 'groove': the border looks as though it were coming out of the canvas.

This allows various interpretations and implementations, and the visual effect is often not that clear. It tends to be clearer when the border is relatively wide. Typically browsers use two different colors to create the impression, the declared border color and a lighter color. This is meant to correspond to an idea of groove or ridge border when light is coming from the direction of the upper left corner. Example:

```html
<style>
  span { border: solid red 10px }
  .groove { border-style: groove }
  .ridge { border-style: ridge }
</style>
<span class=groove>groove</span>
<span class=ridge>ridge</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some [MDN docs on css border-style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-style)

According to this:

> groove: Displays a border leading to a carved effect. **It is the opposite of ridge.**

Answer (score 0):

Groove is a 3D effect that gives the impression that the border is carved into the canvas.
Ridge is a 3D effect that has the opposite effect of groove, in that the border appears to protrude from the canvas.

This link gives you a clear idea:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_border-style